# PHP json_decode function returns a countable error

Tags: php, json

```
$info = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
if (count($info) > 0)
```

My website project has the line of code above. When this loads a JSON file, the following error is produced:

> count(): parameter must be an array or an object that implements countable in

Comment: try this: `json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true)`  it will return array

Answer (score 0):

The function `json_decode()` requires one argument, but it has three additional optional arguments.

The second one is whether or not to return an array. Since the JSON object does not support the countable interface. So to use `count()`, you must request an array.

Here is an example:

```
$info = json_decode(file_get_contents("badjson.jq"), true);
if ($info === null) {
  echo "error\n";
  exit;
}
if (count($info) > 0) {
  echo "count: " . count($info) . "\n";
}
```

If you pass it bad data, you will have this output:

```
error
```

This code checks for `json_decode()` failing to parse the input and exits with a generic error.

Using correctly formatted JSON here:

```
{
    "first": {
        "title": "example"
    },
    "second": {
        "title": "example2"
    }
}
```

You get presented with the count:

```
count: 2
```

For additional information, look up the [`json_decode()` documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Credit Jigar Shah in comments for pointing out the importance of the second argument being true.